Turn.js not displaying the pages properly, animation not displaying
What confuses me the most is that my code is pretty much the same presented here. Nevertheless, my code is not working. I have no errors in the console, but what is displayed in the page is just the first page (partly exceeding the screen). My code is:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Flipbook</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/turn.js/4.1.0/turn.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
        background-color: #efefef;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        }

        .wrapper {
        align-items: center;
        display: flex;
        height: 90%;
        justify-content: center;
        margin: 5%;
        width: 90%;
        }

        .aspect {
        padding-bottom: 70%;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        }

        .aspect-inner {
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        }

        .flipbook {
        height: 100%;
        transition: margin-left 0.25s ease-out;
        width: 100%;
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
        }

        .flipbook .page {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        }

        .flipbook .page img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="aspect">
          <div class="aspect-inner">
            <div class="flipbook" id="flipbook">
              <div class="page"><img src="https://raw.github.com/blasten/turn.js/master/demos/magazine/pages/01.jpg" draggable="false" alt="" /></div>
              <div class="page"><img src="https://raw.github.com/blasten/turn.js/master/demos/magazine/pages/02.jpg" draggable="false" alt="" /></div>
              <div class="page"><img src="https://raw.github.com/blasten/turn.js/master/demos/magazine/pages/03.jpg" draggable="false" alt="" /></div>
              <div class="page"><img src="https://raw.github.com/blasten/turn.js/master/demos/magazine/pages/04.jpg" draggable="false" alt="" /></div>
              <div class="page"><img src="https://raw.github.com/blasten/turn.js/master/demos/magazine/pages/05.jpg" draggable="false" alt="" /></div>
              <div class="page"><img src="https://raw.github.com/blasten/turn.js/master/demos/magazine/pages/06.jpg" draggable="false" alt="" /></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>

By reducing the width of the page with DevTools, I can see that the other pages are displayed below the first one:
What should have happened instead was the images being displayed in succession, flipping with a book page effect when the user clicked on the top-right corner; just as shown in this fiddle.


